# Storing frequencies returned from table function in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of size 5 which stores random digits 0-9 so that there can be multiple occurrences of the same digit. Here is an example vector:

`nums <- c(5,2,5,9,2)`

If I print the results of running the table function on this vector, I get the following output:

```
nums
2 5 9
2 2 1
```

I would like to know what the highest and second highest frequencies are that are returned from `table(nums)`. How can I store all of the frequencies that are returned from an iteration of the `table` function?

Comment: Being more precise would be helpful. I.e., whether your interest is in frequencies alone, in elements corresponding to these frequencies, etc.

Comment: @Julius thanks for the heads up. I think I originally thought it was unnecessary information but now I realize that would have changed the solutions I would have received. I'll keep this in mind in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table` returns an array that can be saved to a variable. If you convert it to a data.frame using `as.data.frame` you get an easier to work with object:

```
nums <- c(5,2,5,9,2)
tab <- as.data.frame(table(nums))
tab

  nums Freq
1    2    2
2    5    2
3    9    1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. I should have been more specific that all I am concerned with is the frequencies and not anything else that you can see when you run `print(table(nums))`. As a data frame I can easily store the last column of data as a vector which gives me the ability to reference each individual frequency.

Answer (score 1):

To shrink the table only to the two most frequent options you would want

```
sort(table(nums), dec = TRUE)[1:2]
# nums
# 2 5 
# 2 2
```

Just to get their names you could do

```
names(sort(table(nums), dec = TRUE))[1:2]
# [1] "2" "5"
```

If it may happen that there are not that many unique values, you could use `na.omit`, as in

```
names(sort(table(nums), dec = TRUE))[1:4]
# [1] "2" "5" "9" NA
na.omit(names(sort(table(nums), dec = TRUE))[1:4])
# [1] "2" "5" "9"
# attr(,"na.action")
# [1] 4
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "omit"
```

As for storing the results, using a list should be pretty convenient:

```
tabs <- list()
tabs[[1]] <- sort(table(nums), dec = TRUE)[1:2]
tabs[[2]] <- sort(table(c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3)), dec = TRUE)[1:2]
tabs
# [[1]]
# nums
# 2 5 
# 2 2 
#
# [[2]]
#
# 1 3 
# 2 2
```

In particular, using lists is compatible with the option that the number of options is varying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plyr, its lightening fast.

```
library(plyr)
nums <- c(5,2,5,9,2)
count(nums)
```

**Result**

```
 x   freq
 2    2
 5    2
 9    1
```